# REST/Rails questions - support for HTTP methods?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, http-method

So I am getting this error for one of my routes. I'am running Rails v2.3.8 + Mongrel 1.1.5. Does rails support only GET & POST??

```
ActionController::MethodNotAllowed (Only get and post requests are allowed.):
```

The route defined in my routes.rb is -

```
map.connect "#{base_url}/r/:id/rate?v=:value&u=:user_id", :conditions => { :method => :put }, :controller => 'mycontroller', :action => 'myaction'
```

Comment: No, Rails supports all standard HTTP methods (GET POST PUT DELETE). Show the rest of your routes.rb - it might be hitting the wrong route.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not mean that Rails support only these two methods. It means, that route that matched request (by URL) did not match any controller method (by http method).